# Convert Date in C# to "PTHM"

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core

I am confused as to how to convert a given date to the format oh "PT_H_M".
For example, date of 2018-06-28T14:47:59.79-04:00, should be PT14H47M.

thanks

Comment: It seems that your question is about formatting a duration using ISO 8601. However, a "date" (point in time) is not a duration. Is your question really about going from a date to a duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does PT mean? Is the hour stamp affected by the timezone and adjusted for time saving?

If not,

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now; 
string pdDate = string.Format("PT{0}H{1}M", date.ToString("HH"), date.ToString("mm"));
```

Comment: just simpler string.Format(@"{0:\P\THH\Hmm\M}", date)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about the question, whether it's just a formatting issue or what.  But here's a stab at it...

C# version

```
DateTime dateX = DateTime.Now;
String formattedString = String.Format("PT{0}H{1}M" , dateX.Hour, dateX.Minute);
```

VB version (can ignore! sorry)

```
Dim dateX as DateTime = DateTime.Now        
Dim formattedString as string = String.Format("PT{0}H{1}M" , dateX.Hour, dateX.Minute)
```

The output would be: PT19H51M

Comment: He said C#, not VB :)

Comment: Hah! Thanks, sorry.  Been reading different forums.  Will update it.